# Perforce equivalent to svn propset svn:externals

Tags: svn, perforce

We would like to be able to push Stream imports out to different IP Depots with a script, something we used to do with 'svn propset svn:externals' before switching over to Perforce. Does anyone have any experience of this type of automation they can share please?

Answer (score 0):

The Perforce stream `import` mapping is quite similar, in that you are able to mirror another part of a Perforce depot into your stream.

`import my_code/... //other_depot/other_code/...@1234`

There is a good blog article on the 14.1 stream at change feature [here](http://www.perforce.com/blog/140416/new-141-frozen-stream-imports).

If your source code is located in more that one Perforce server, you may need to set up a [remote](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_depot.html#p4_depot.remote) depot to view the code, or use a script like [P4Transfer](https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce-software-p4transfer) to mirror it.